# Create a list comprised of items missing in a list

Tags: java, java-8

I have two lists.

The first one is the object ManagerStoreId, consisting of two properties: Manager and StoreId e.g:

```
List<ManagerStoreId> managerStoreIdList;

public ManagerStoreId {
   private String manager;
   private String productId;
}
```

The second is Manager:

```
List<String> Manager;
```

I want to create a third list:

```
List<String> managerNotFoundInManagerStoreIdList
```

which is a list of managers that don't exist in ManagerStoreId.

What's the best way of going about it?

I have thought about looping through the `managerStoreIdList` and then doing some sort of check to see if the string using a getManager method. But how do I know to add it back to the list if it doesn't list?

Comment: What are your thoughts about how you might attempt this task?  You've tagged [java-stream]; have you attempted this with a `Stream`?

Comment: Sorry - I've added these to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to compute `managerNotFoundInManagerStoreIdList`. Here's the simplest one:

Create a set of `manager` and look it up:

```
Set<String> managers = managerStoreIdList.stream().map(ManagerStoreId::getManager)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<String> managerNotFoundInManagerStoreIdList = Manager.stream()
    .filter(m -> !managers.contains(m))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```